# send json responses but with lots of data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem where the data that I send to my view doesn't match the amount of data that the query generates. only single data appears.

this is my function :

```js
function lokasi_ajax() {
  var kode_lokasi = $('#kode_lokasi').val();

  $.ajax({
   url : '<?= base_url() ?>index.php/asset/asset_dijual_proses/lokasi_ajax',
   data: 'kode_lokasi='+kode_lokasi,
   success : function (data) {
    var json = data;
    value = JSON.parse(json);

    console.log(value.kode_aset);

   }
  });
 }
```

this is the method on my controller :

```html
function lokasi_ajax()
 {
  $kode_lokasi = $_GET['kode_lokasi'];
  $data =array();

  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_reg, item_lokasi, item_barang FROM asset_item 
   WHERE item_lokasi= '$kode_lokasi'");
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   $data = array(
    'kode_aset' => $row->id_reg,
    'item_lokasi' => $row->item_lokasi,
    'item_barang' => $row->item_barang 
   );
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

the amount of data that should be generated is like this picture :

[result data from dbms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYjfk.png)

but from the response json only displays one data like this :
[json response result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSdtA.png)

Comment: because `$data` is overwritten every iteration, thus you only get one (last row), change it to `$data[] =` to continually push inside the `$data` array

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach loop reassigns the data. you need to add it to the array.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        'kode_aset' => $row->id_reg,
        'item_lokasi' => $row->item_lokasi,
        'item_barang' => $row->item_barang 
    );
}
```